# A set of classes with similar interfaces but different method signatures

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, inheritance, design-patterns

I have a growing number of worker classes which share a very similar interface but use different parameters in their methods. They look somewhat like this:

```
class SomeWorker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit SomeWorker(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~SomeWorker();

public slots:
    void doWork( /* various params */ );

signals:
    void signalResultReady( /* various param */ );
    void signalError(QString errorMessage);
    void signalStatus(QString status);
    void signalProgress(int progress);    
};
```

Because these classes take various parameters for `doWork()` method and return different objects through `signalResultReady()` signal I have a problem with creating a base `Worker` class which would specify the common interface. On the other hand I feel there must some more elegant design which would allow me to avoid code duplication or at least enforce the common interface in all the classes.

Comment: If they don't share the same `doWork()` and `signalResultReady()` signatures, your classes can't use polymorphic/virtual access, so a common interface couldn't cover those pieces exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer creating base structure for ***various params*** [VARIOUS_PARAMS], and 
make a base class for my worker classes , which defines  doWork(VARIOUS_PARAMS * param) , 
and make different VARIOUS_PARAMS sub structures.

struct VARIOUS_PARAMS_SOME_CLASS : VARIOUS_PARAMS
{
};

Comment: This is pretty much the route I've eventually chosen.

Answer (score 0):

I would define the base class as follows:

```
class BaseWorker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    BaseWorker (QObject *parent = 0);
    ~SomeWorker();

signals:
    void signalError(QString errorMessage);
    void signalStatus(QString status);
    void signalProgress(int progress);    
};
```

And the worker class(es) in the following way:

```
class SomeWorker : public BaseWorker
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    SomeWorker(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~SomeWorker();

public slots:
    void doWork( /* various params */ );

signals:
    void signalResultReady( /* various param */ );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

if the member functions :

```
void doWork( /* various params */ );
void signalResultReady( /* various param */ );
```

receive the same number of arguments and differ only in their type, you can use template like this (let's assume they expect 3 arguments as input):

```
template<class T1, class T2, class T3> void doWork(T1 a1, T2 a2, T3 a3);
template<class Z1, class Z2, class Z3> void signalResultReady(Z1 b1, Z2 b2, Z3 b3);
```